# I tried to format my sportsPerson like first letter alone in caps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

Can you tell me why the below error is happening. I tried to format my `sportsPerson` like first letter alone in caps. I am getting a syntax error. Can you tell me how to fix it. I am providing my code below.

```
/src/components/sports/tracker/sports-tracker-tile.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/workspace/basketball/src/components/sports/tracker/sports-tracker-tile.jsx: Unexpected token (80:76)
```

const sportsPerson = this.props.profile.firstName;
      78 |         return (
      79 |

> 80 |                 {`Want some advice${sportsPerson && sportsPerson.length > 0 ?`, `<span style={{'text-transform': 'capitalize'}}>`${sportsPerson.toLowerCase()}``` </span>`` : ''}? ```}

Comment: why do you use comma ( , ) ? and i think there is something wrong with your quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest this approach, your ternary isn't formatted correctly which is causing the JS error. Instead I would use a variable like:

```
var playerName = sportsPerson || '';

var content = playerName ? <span style={{'text-transform': 'capitalize'}}>, {playerName.toLowerCase()}</span> 
: '';
```

and then in your h4 just do this.

```
<h4>Want some advice{content}?</h4>
```

Comment: whats the use of this line var playerName = sportsPerson || '';
 i am little confused :(

Comment: playerName will equal sportsPerson if sportsPerson is defined/not a falsey value, if sportsPerson is undefined or a falsey value it will become default to an empty string

Comment: Its the same as doing `var playerName = sportsPerson ? sportsPerson : ''`

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird logic and missing curly brace on line 80. Check your braces and quotes.